# Unit test for url.parse call

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a very simple wrapper class in Typescript:

```
import { parse, UrlWithParsedQuery } from 'url';

export class Utils {

    public static parseUrl(url: string): UrlWithParsedQuery {
        return parse(url, true);
    }

}
```

How can I unit test the call to the parse method?
In my unit test this approach doesn't want to work:

```
jest.spyOn('url', parse); // error: No overload matches this call.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { parse, UrlWithParsedQuery } from 'url';

export class Utils {
  public static parseUrl(url: string): UrlWithParsedQuery {
    return parse(url, true);
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { Utils } from './';
import url from 'url';

describe('60884651', () => {
  it('should parse url', () => {
    const parseSpy = jest.spyOn(url, 'parse');
    const actual = Utils.parseUrl('http://stackoverflow.com');
    expect(actual.href).toBe('http://stackoverflow.com/');
    expect(actual.protocol).toBe('http:');
    expect(parseSpy).toBeCalledWith('http://stackoverflow.com', true);
    parseSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60884651/index.test.ts
  60884651
    ✓ should parse url (10ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.104s, estimated 10s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I wasn't doing the right import. However, when I use import url from 'url', I get a Module '"url"' has no default export error. It finally works with import url = require('url');